# Homotopy Poincaré conjecture - no map inducing the isomorphism on homology

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$
In Terence Tao's [notes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0610903v1.pdf) on page 18, concerning the [Poincaré conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_conjecture), he gave the following sketchy proof of the homotopy Poincaré conjecture.

Given $M^3$ a 3-manifold with $\pi_1(M^3)=0$, then automatically $0=H_1(X,\Z)=H^2(X,\Z)=H_2(X,\Z)$.  Moreover the action of $\pi_1(M_3) \curvearrowright H^{n-1}(S^{n-1},\Z)$ where $S^{n-1} \hookrightarrow Sp(T(M^3)) \to M^3$ is the fiber of the sphere bundle over the basepoint of $M$, is trivial since $\pi_1(M^3)=0$, so that $M^3$ is orientable. Therefore $H^3(M^3,\Z)=\Z$ and $H^i(M^3,\Z)=0$ for $i>3$ because $M^3$ is a 3 dimensional manifold (easy argument from excision).

Terence Tao then says that it follows from the [Whitehead theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead_theorem) that $M^3 \to S^3$ is a homotopy equivalence. It **does not follow** since there is no map inducing the isomorphisms on homology between $S^3$ and $M^3$.

Is there a Postnikov decomposition trick to show that we don't need the map to induce the isomorphism or is there an obvious map that I am missing?

Comment: Two things: first, that is a crazy argument to show $M$ it orientable; that already follows from being simply connected. Second, you have the degree map.

Comment: Sorry, I learned the sphere bundle definition o orientability first because I learned it out of spanier(he covers fiber bundles first) then midget and tangora before reading hatcher.  So that is my first recourse.

Comment: besides it is very intuitive :).  It is the condition that if you go walk around the surface in any loop, then you will come back facing the same way. So if I want to actually show that $\pi_1(M^3)=0 \Rightarrow M^3$ is orientable, without quoting theorems, I could either use the homological fundamental class definition, the thom class cohomology definition, basis for the determinant bundle definition, or the one above.   If you ask me this is the most intuitive way of proving it and is far from crazy.

Comment: Fair enough.  Seems that saying "oh, it has no connected double cover, so it must be orientable" is pretty intuitive, since the construction of the double cover for a non-orientable manifold is straightforward.  But different strokes, different folks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to produce such a map. One is the approach given by Mike Miller. Another is using two applications of the Hurewicz theorem: one shows that $\pi_2 = 0$, and the second shows that $\pi_3 \cong H_3 \cong \mathbb{Z}$. The map $f : S^3 \to M$ given by a generator of $\pi_3$ then induces an isomorphism on homology, and hence (by homology Whitehead) is a homotopy equivalence.

Comment: OH duh it's just given by the fundamental class.  ...sigh

Comment: It's funny: I find that, almost uniformly, differentially-minded people give the answer I did; and algebraically minded folks give yours.

Comment: @Mike: I was going to give both, starting with yours, but then you posted your answer!

Answer (score 4):

If $M$ is a connected $n$-manifold, pick any closed embedded disc $D$ and consider the canonical map $M \to M/(M \setminus \text{int}(D)) \cong S^n$. The degree of this map is one, and hence if $M$ is a homology sphere, this is a homology isomorphism. The assumption that $\pi_1 = 0$ then implies it's a homotopy equivalence by Hurewicz and Whitehead.

Comment: Is it possible to think of this as kinda similar to a pontryagin Thom map?